# Add blank spaces at sql result

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help to add a significant amount of blank spaces at the back of sql result.

My code is like this:

```
select 
lpad(account,10,'0')||
lpad(type,3,'0') from tbl_account;
```

The above result should be "1234500000NEW", but i need to add 5 blank spaces at the back of the result, so the result should be like this "1234500000NEW     ".

Hope someone can help me on this.

*additional info: the blank spaces i need to add is more than 5, maybe its 100, or maybe more. depends on the data produced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is the best way as I'm pretty sure there is a concat function somewhere, but you should be able to simple do:

```
+ '     '
```

at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
select lpad(account,10,'0')|| lpad(type,3,'0')||'     ' yourcolname 
from tbl_account;
```

Result

```
1234500000NEW
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rpad Function in the same way:

```
select rpad(lpad(account,10,'0')|| lpad(type,3,'0'), 5, ' ') from tbl_account;
```